# Did Adi Shankara logically prove the existence of heaven?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

We know that Adi Shankara believed in heaven, but did Adi Shankara prove the existence of heaven with logic, like he proved the existence of Brahman and reincarnation?

Also, did he use the concept of heaven in his debates?

Note: By heaven, I mean heaven as a real place somewhere in the universe and not as a state of mind.

Comment: There is no need to apply any logic in terms of religion. Scriptural references are ultimate authority.And above all Adi Shankaracharya's words alone prove the point as he himself is considered  such a authority in Hinduism.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar why, adi shankara proved the existence of Brahman with logic why not heaven

Comment: Can you explain where Shankara proves brahman solely by using logic?

Comment: @zero https://youtu.be/YZoAnVXZGZ4, I am not asking only logic but logic in general.

Comment: The link shows them discussing on the basis of scriptures. Heaven, can also be known similarly through scriptures.

Comment: Sankara, as the vedas say, asserts that the heavens are only temporary abodes. Sankara used logic, but he deferred to Brahma Sutras which says that the only 'proof' of Brahman is in scriptures. See Brahma Sutras 1.1.3 and 1.1.4 - "But that (Brahman is to be known only from the scriptures and not independently by any other means is established) because It is the main purport (of all Vedanta texts)."